# Error Unexpected token en la consola de google search

Tags: google-search-console

Alguien no puedo mandar este comando y no encuentro quien me ayude:

```JavaScript
> })

})

)

})
  }else{swal.fire({
           title:`enter valid amount',
           icon: " warning"})}

 })
 
 }else{swal.fire({
          title:"enter a valid Email",
          icon:"warning"
          });}

 })


  }, 3000)
```

Y obtengo este error por la consola:

`(X) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'             VM129:1`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Diego Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow En español, es recomendable poner el código en la pregunta y el error también. En las imágenes puede verse borroso en las personas con problema de vista o dificulta la transcripción de este mismo. Como eres nuevo te invito a visitar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Ahora que veo con claridad el código te puedo nombrar un error que si puedo estar seguro. En el primer else swal.fire({ haces title: ` y no cierra con el mismo operador sino que usas otro operador ' . Puedes arreglar esa parte usando las comillas simple o doble sin combinar operadores: }else{swal.fire({
           title:'enter valid amount',   . O si lo vas a combinar asegúrate de cerrar la cadena con el mismo signo que usaste al abrirla: 'Hola "no" mundo';

Comment: Si tu código tiene mas errores, desconozco la respuesta. Este poquito de código no contiene suficiente información para saber si cerraste bien o no una o muchas funciones. Porfavor agrega mas código y mejora la descripción para que sepamos que intentaste hacer.

Comment: 1.- El código como texto por favor. 2.- tienes mal cerradas las comillas